# Trouble testing for prime numbers

Tags: c++, primes

Hi I'm doing a prime number work for class, and I'm running into a problem. Could someone please help me a little bit?

With some numbers it will work but other numbers it won't:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "cmath"
#include "ctime"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num;
    int i = 2;
    int result;
    cout << "What is the prime you want to enter";
    cin >> num;

    for(; i < num; i++){
        result = num / i;
    }

    if (num % i == 0) {
        cout << "Your number is not prime\nIt is divisble by: " << i << endl;
    }

    if(num % i != 0){
        cout << "your number is prime\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect this code to work? Why do you calculate `result` but never use it? What value do you expect `i` to have when control passes out of the loop, and how are you testing for primality? You must work on simpler problems before attempting this one.

Comment: Look closely at your `for` loop. What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Off topic: spend some time researching sieve algorithms. It will make your job a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

this `if (num % i == 0) {` .... must be done inside the loop, otherwise you are going to check only the last value of i